# Facebook App - Javascript Set Height of Canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, height

I am trying to set the height so I don't have a scrollbar in my facebook app, seen [HERE](http://www.facebook.com/BurkettRestaurantEquipment?sk=app_175743219164675)

I have used jQuery to create the canvas plugin using the GRAPH API and have tried adding the following codes to edit the height but none work.  Anyone have any ideas?

In my scripts.js I try adding the following to the bottom:

```
FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();  //doesn't work
```

Also tried the following:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 2500 });
}; //doesn't work either
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.Canvas.setSize({height: 1050});
}

// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
function sizeChangeCallback() {
   FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have added it but it still seems to do it.  Is it because I dont actually have a FB.init in my file?  I used part of a tutorial that used jQuery and I don't see anywhere where I put FB.init (though the app works).

Comment: Yeah.. Also you sould add `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>` and `<script>
FB.init({
appId : 'here_your_API_id',
status : true,
cookie : true,
xfbml : true
});
</script>`

Comment: Bingo, needed to add the FB.init, thank you for the troubleshoot. I have another question I will be posting soon about a different subject on my facebook app, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification for other users who happen on this content:

- Add the

  `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>` and `<script> FB.init({ appId : 'here_your_API_id', status : true, cookie : true, xfbml : true }); </script>`

  code before your `</head>` tag.
- Add the 
  `<div id="fb-root"></div>`

`<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>`

```
`<script>window.fbAsyncInit = function() {FB.Canvas.setSize({height: 1050});}`
`function sizeChangeCallback() {FB.Canvas.setSize();}</script>`
```

portion right before the `</body>` tag.

- If all else fails, try the following:

  `<style>body {width:500px; height:1050px;overflow:hidden;margin:0; padding:0; border:0;}</style>`

Comment: Thanks! I've been struggling with this for quite some time. It had times when it worked, times when it didn't, it acted different on different browsers. But using your tip made it work fine! Hopefully, others will see your helpful comment too! Thanks again